# Project-open on Fedora server

Tags: fedora, project-open

I want to install ]project open[ version 4 on fedora server.can anyone tell me what are the exact procedure/steps to install it from scratch..any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are instructions for installing ]project-open[ 4.0 on CentOS 6, which should be quite similar: http://www.project-open.com/en/install-rhel-6. However, I'm not aware of any installation or installation request specifically on Fedora. Just make sure to use PostgreSQL 8.4 (exactly this version!). You might have to compile PG from source for this.

As an alternative you could install KVM on your Fedora system and convert ]po[ V4.0 VMware. Instructions are available for example here: https://access.redhat.com/articles/1351473